# Thom space functor preserves homotopy

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, quotient-spaces, principal-bundles

Let $X$ be a paracompact space and consider two **homotopic maps** $f,g: X\to B$, where $E\to B$ is a real vector bundle over a paracompact space $B$. We know that these maps have isomorphic pullback bundles $E'\to X$, where we can assume that the corresponding maps $f',g': E'\to E$ are metric-preserving.

Are the induced maps of Thom spaces $Th(f),Th(g): Th(E')\to Th(E)$ also homotopic?

Comment: The maps $Th(f)$, $Th(g)$ actually have different domains, namely $Th(f^*E)$ and $Th(g^*E)$. As you point out these spaces are homeomorphic (at least homotopy equivalent), but they are not the same space.

Comment: @Tyrone thank you for the correction. Let us call $\varphi: Th(f^*E) \to Th(g^*E)$ the map induced by the isomorphism $f^*E \cong g^*E$. Are $Th(f)$ and $Th(g) \circ \varphi$ homotopic?

Comment: I don't think there is a canonical isomorphism, $\varphi$ to choose here.